# Create an instance of WindowInsetsCompat

Tags: android, androidx, windowinsets

**Core version**: *androidx.core:core:1.0.1*

Is there any proper way for creating `WindowInsetsCompat`'s instance?
As I see, it has the private constructor:

```
private WindowInsetsCompat(Object insets) {
    mInsets = insets;
}
```

It's called from 5 methods and 1 static wrapper, that has package-private visibility:

```
static WindowInsetsCompat wrap(Object insets) {
    return insets == null ? null : new WindowInsetsCompat(insets);
}
```

That `wrap` method only used at 6 methods inside `ViewCompat`, that's all.

So, can we create an instance of WindowInsetsCompat somehow?
Or, the only way is cmd+c/cmd+v?

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions to create an instance of `WindowInsetsCompat`.

### First solution

You can use reflection to call the private constructor:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class WindowInsetsCompatHelper {

    public static WindowInsetsCompat createWindowInsetsCompat(Object insets) {
        try {
            Constructor<WindowInsetsCompat> constructor = WindowInsetsCompat.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Object.class);
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            return constructor.newInstance(insets);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

### Second solution

It requires to create a helper class in the package `androidx.core.view`. After that you can directly use the `wrap` method:

```
package androidx.core.view;

public class WindowInsetsCompatHelper {

    public static WindowInsetsCompat createWindowInsetsCompat(Object insets) {
        return WindowInsetsCompat.wrap(insets);
    }
}
```